# How to Embed HTML code inside email using PHP

Tags: php, html, email, embed, email-formats

I want to include an html meta tag inside an email which we are sending using PHP.

```
<meta name=\"yyyy\" content=\"uuuuu\" />
```

I'm expecting the email like:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for subscribing. Please include the below code in `<head>`
>
> `<meta name=\"yyyy\" content=\"uuuuu\" />`
>
> Thanks & Regards,
>
> yy

What is the best way to include html code inside email which will work for all email servers like Gmail, Outlook etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the function you need :

```
$codeValue = htmlspecialchars("<meta name=\"yyyy\" content=\"uuuuu\" />");
```

This way the code won't be interprated

Comment: I would experiment with the [css inline code element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code)

Comment: Oh I was aware of the code bbcode but not of the html tag. Thanks for the add.